# Github home page

Tags: github, url, sites

I know how to make an HTML site on GitHub with URLs like:

> [username].github.io/[somthing]

but I am wondering how to make a URL without that project name or "[something]" to be just

> [username].github.io

I know I can do this on https://pages.github.com/ by naming it by my username, but then the URL is:

> [username].github.io/[username]

Comment: Name your home page HTML file in the root of your repository `index.html`.

Comment: You're asking about the difference between a *user site* and a *project site*. The documentation for this is [here](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/about-github-pages#types-of-github-pages-sites); in short, you have to create a repository with the name `YOURNAME.github.io`, and it'll be visible at `https://YOURNAME.github.io` instead of `YOURNAME.github.io/REPONAME`.

Comment: Yes, but when I do that  URL is [username].github.io/[username]. I named it like you said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when I do that URL is `[username].github.io/[username]`.

From "[Types of GitHub Pages sites](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/about-github-pages#types-of-github-pages-sites)", it should *not* be that URL.

> To publish a user site, you must create a repository owned by your personal account that's named `<username>.github.io`.
>
> Unless you're using a custom domain, user and organization sites are available at `http(s)://<username>.github.io` or `http(s)://<organization>.github.io`.

Example: https://github.com/square/square.github.io gives you https://square.github.io/, not https://square.github.io/square.